# Generating a table of differences between two dictionaries

Tags: c#, hash-map

```
for (int i = 0; i < keyList.Count; i++)
{
    if (oldDic.ContainsKey(keyList[i].ToString()))
    {
        if (newDic[keyList[i].ToString()].ToString() == oldDic[keyList[i].ToString()].ToString())
        {
            //ReminderBackupLog("Same");
        }
        else
        {
            isChnagedSectionFields = "Yes";
            string oldValue = oldDic[keyList[i].ToString()].ToString();
            string newValue = newDic[keyList[i].ToString()].ToString();
            table = table + "<tr style='border: 1px solid black;'><td style='border: 1px solid black;'>" + colNames[keyList[i].ToString()].ToString() + "</td><td style='border: 1px solid black;'>" + oldValue + "</td><td style='border: 1px solid black;'>" + newValue + "</td></tr>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        isChnagedSectionFields = "Yes";
        string newValues = newDic[keyList[i].ToString()].ToString();
        table = table + "<tr style='border: 1px solid black;'><td style='border: 1px solid black;'>" + colNames[keyList[i].ToString()].ToString() + "</td><td style='border: 1px solid black;'>" + " " + "</td><td style='border: 1px solid black;'>" + newValues + "</td></tr>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should separate the logic from your representation and first collect those differences in a separate list. Also, what are the types of your dictionaries? All those `ToString()`s make it really noisy and are likely not necessary. Furthermore, use a `foreach` loop to iterate through your key list, this will also automatically get rid of all those `keyList[i]` accesses. And finally, instead of appending to a string directly, use a [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) to make it more efficient:

```
// Use a separate type to collect your diffs
class DiffEntry
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public string OldValue { get; set; }
    public string NewValue { get; set; }
}

// collect all diffs
List<DiffEntry> diffs = new List<DiffEntry>();
foreach (string key in keyList)
{
    if (oldDic.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        if (newDic[key] != oldDic[key])
        {
            diffs.Add(new DiffEntry()
            {
                ColumnName = colNames[key],
                OldValue = oldDic[key],
                newValue = newDic[key]
            });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        diffs.Add(new DiffEntry()
        {
            ColumnName = newDic,
            NewValue = newDic[key]
        });
    }
}

// generate the actual table output
StringBuilder tableContent = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DiffEntry diff in diffs)
{
    tableContent.Append("<tr style='border: 1px solid black;'>");
    tableContent.Append("<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>");
    tableContent.Append(diff.ColumnName);
    tableContent.Append("</td><td style='border: 1px solid black;'>");
    tableContent.Append(diff.OldValue);
    tableContent.Append("</td><td style='border: 1px solid black;'>");
    tableContent.Append(diff.NewValue);
    tableContent.Append("</td></tr>");
}
table += tableContent.ToString();
```

Comment: type of your dictionaries is ToString()

Comment: @poke May I suggest an improvement to DiffEntry class. You can add an enum ChangeAction to group the differences e.g. if the matching entry are different or an entirely new entry is there in newDic.

Answer (score 0):

How about a generic solution using LINQ?

```
private string GetDiffTableRows<TKey, TValue>(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> oldValues, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> newValues)
{
    TValue oldValue, newValue;
    var diffs = oldValues.Keys.Concat(newValues.Keys).Distinct().Select(k => new
    {
        Key = k,
        OldHasKey = oldValues.TryGetValue(k, out oldValue),
        NewHasKey = newValues.TryGetValue(k, out newValue),
        OldValue = oldValue,
        NewValue = newValue
    }).Where(d => d.OldHasKey != d.NewHasKey || !Equals(d.OldValue, d.NewValue));

    var tableRows = diffs.Select(d => string.Format(DiffTableRowFormatString, d.Key, d.OldValue, d.NewValue));
    return string.Join(string.Empty, tableRows);
}

private const string DiffTableRowFormatString =
    "<tr style='border: 1px solid black;'>" +
        "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>{0}</td>" +
        "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>{1}</td>" +
        "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>{2}</td>" +
    "</tr>";
```